# Language and font problems in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, locale

I'm a Dutchman living in Hungary. I use a Dell Inspiron I7, 5000 series laptop with a Hungarian keyboard and Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa 64 bit. My Mint-system language is Dutch, language setting "Hungarian (standard)", because most of my papers, calculations etc. are in Hungarian.

Most important programs, like LibreOffice and the "terminal" function well, but "simple" text editors like "Gedit" or "Notepadqq", or even the file manager, don't accept Hungarian characters. For example, `Áá Éé Íí óÓ Öö Őő Úú Üü Űű`. I already tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and the only error message is:

```
Error: Bad entry 'nl_AW '
```

Before, when I was running Mint 17.2, everything was fine until a certain moment, some months ago. After updating to Mint 17.3 this "failure (?)" still exists. How could I repair this? I'm not a geek or technician, just a simple user!

2016-march-21: after some things I have tried, the result of "locale" is:

```
LANG=nl_AW.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=  
LC_CTYPE="nl_AW.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_TIME=nl_AW.UTF-8  
LC_COLLATE="nl_AW.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_MESSAGES="nl_AW.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_NAME=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_ADDRESS=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_TELEPHONE=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_MEASUREMENT=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_IDENTIFICATION=hu_HU.UTF-8  
LC_ALL=
```

and the result of regenerating the locales

```
:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales  
[sudo] password:   
Generating locales...      
  de_AT.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  de_BE.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  de_CH.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  de_DE.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  de_LI.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  de_LU.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  hu_HU.UTF-8... up-to-date  
Error: Bad entry 'nl_AW '  
  nl_AW.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  nl_AW.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  nl_BE.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  nl_NL.UTF-8... up-to-date  
  ro_RO.UTF-8... up-to-date  
Generation complete.
```

My hard disk has a separated Home partition. Should I newly install Linux Mint and all programs to make a fresh start?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `locale` (open a  terminal and run the command there, then paste the output into your question using the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code).

Comment: It seems that you have your system configured to *use* `nl_AW`, but not to *support* it. I presume that Mint has a GUI for that but I have no idea what. After telling us the output of `locale`, try running `sudo locale-gen nl_AW.utf8` (I'm not sure if it will solve your problem but it can't cause any harm).